# django-imagekit generateimages command fail

Tags: django, django-imagekit

I'm using django 1.5 and django-imagekit==3.0.1

My settings.py modifications:

`IMAGEKIT_CACHEFILE_DIR = MEDIA_ROOT + '/imges_cache'`

model fields:

```
photo = models.ImageField(_(u"Photo"), upload_to="user_photos/",
                          blank=True, null=True)
thumb = ImageSpecField([ResizeToFill(129, 129)], source='photo')
thumb_small = ImageSpecField([ResizeToFill(49, 48)], source='photo')
```

problem is when I run command:

`python manage.py generateimages`

I get this:

```
Validating generator: cv:personalinfo:thumb_small
 /home/user/app/static_files/media/imges_cache/user_photos/photo1/9b9a3c24f189efc6117357427a9f8b33.jpg
    FAILED: function takes at most 11 arguments (13 given)
Validating generator: cv:personalinfo:thumb
  /home/user/app/static_files/media/imges_cache/user_photos/photo1/fe6c67625b129ceffcd65f197413b7f9.jpg
    FAILED: function takes at most 11 arguments (13 given)
Validating generator: imagekit:thumbnail
```

So I can't generate cache files.

Comment: Please post a full stacktrace

Comment: Imagekit command catches all exceptions while generating images so it is a all stacktrace what I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're having the problem described in [Issue #193](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit/issues/193). In summary, you've got a global install of PIL but a local install of Pillow and the two aren't compatible. Check out [Issue #173 on the Pillow project](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/173) for more info.

Comment: It was indeed problem with PIL and Pillow compatibility. I had both installed in venv, to fix problem I removed PIL completely and now it is working. Thanks for help.